# Export sheet as workbook (values only)

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to export several sheets from an existing workbook to a new one, but despite I have included this instruction:

```
.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value
```

The output still includes formulas.

Here is the whole code:

```
Sub Sheet_SaveAs()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim Path As String

'Defining Strings

Path = "%MYPATH%"

'XLS Generator

Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")).Copy
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
With wb
 .ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value
 .SaveAs Path & "Example" & ".xlsx"
 .Close False
End With
End Sub
```

What am I missing?

Comment: It's not a good idea to use `ActiveSheet`. This is because active sheet might not be the sheet you want to reference. Qualify your sheet (i.e. `With wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")`. Same applies to things like `.Select` and `.Activate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refer to the workbook's sheets by their name, not the active one:

```
wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Value = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Value
```

To iterate through all the sheets you copied:

```
Dim varSheetNames As Variant: varSheetNames = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")
' ...
Sheets(varSheetNames).Copy ' Note: ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets or ThisWorkbook.Worksheets (depending on where your code is) would be better
' ...
Dim varName As Variant: For Each varName In varSheetNames
    With wb.Worksheets(varName).UsedRange
        .Value = .Value
    End With
Next varName
```